# How to embed LLVM IR interpreter into other languages?

Tags: ocaml, llvm, interpreter, execution, llvm-ir

I'm trying to embed LLVM IR Interpreter into OCaml.

What I want to do is the following process:

(1) Read LLVM IR files

(2) Draw CFG(control flow graph) from IR

(3) execute(or interpret) each IR codes in basic blocks, with accepting the previous state(or memory) and generating the next state

(1) and (2) are done, but there are no references about step (3).
I used `llvm` library of OCaml and `opt` with `-dot-cfg` for drawing CFGs. But I'm having a difficult time to grasp how to interpret(or execute in-memory) IR codes with OCaml, since I'm new to LLVM.

If there are any other methods to execute LLVM IR in memory with different kinds of language, it will be helpful too.

Comment: Self-promotion which does not answer the question: I wrote a nice library for (1) and (2): https://github.com/Drup/llvmgraph

Comment: regarding 3) there's a proper tutorial here: http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html
Unfortunately it does not cover how to directly compile IR code. My best bet would be to parse it and create the proper structures in-memory using the methods described in said tutorial.

Comment: Note that I'm pretty sure there are no LLVM interpreter for the IR, so I think you will have  to write your own.

Comment: You can execute the IR in memory with something called execution engine: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html  Here is example code using execution engine to execute code: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/examples/HowToUseJIT/HowToUseJIT.cpp#L125  For more examples you can look at the JIT tutorial that is available on llvm website. I am afraid that all of these examples are in C++ so not sure how to exactly embed them in OCaml.

Comment: @drup I'm actually using that library for (1) and (2). I didn't expect the writer of that library would comment for my question... wow. thank you so much!

Comment: @antipattern Thanks. I'm now trying to read the necessary parts of llvm codes to implement what I want, and the link you gave to me would be very helpful too. thank you again!

Comment: @deLta I know the existence of ExecutionEngine, but I couldn't find any already-made libraries or some sorts of things that properly using it, which would help me saving time if exists. But the code from your link might be helpful because now I'm implementing my own, so thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, the llvm engine has OCaml bindings (in the official ones): https://llvm.moe/ocaml/Llvm_executionengine.html

Comment: @Drup I read that article, but I couldn't find any function to execute llvm ir in memory. Function `run_static_ctor` and `run_static_dtor` is not a function to execute ir, as I know. And there's no interface for ir execution.. If I'm wrong, please let me know!